# I can't submit a form with Dojo DateTextBox

Tags: dojo

I'm working on a project with struts2 and dojo. Our dojo version is 1.4.x
I can't submit a form with DateTextBox control when my browser language is English.
However, when I change the local into other language like ZH_CN, it works.
I'm wondering why this would happen.

Here is my jsp code snippet:

```
<div id="projectForm" dojotype="dijit.form.Form">
    <!-- end Date -->
    <span class="manager_create_from_components">
        <s:text name="manager.create.endDate"></s:text>
    </span>
    <input type="text" name="project.endDate" constraints="{datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd'}" dojotype="dijit.form.DateTextBox"><br />
</div>
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors on submitting the form when the locale is English?
Can you provide the error messages that you got which would be helpful to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't get javascript errors on submitting the form. And the error message is here. HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action com.ternwit.tms.web.action.ManagerAction and result input. Actually, I don't think this error message helps. Before this project, I had met this error type, if any mistake appear on web page, like format mistake, struts 2 will report this error message. So I'm thinking about the date format may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action
>   com.ternwit.tms.web.action.ManagerAction and result input.

This error is due to the fact you don't specified a result page in your struts.xml

```
<action name="actionName" class="package.yourClass" method="yourMethod">
        <result name="success">successPage.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">errorPage.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">errorPage.jsp (or yourFormPage.jsp)</result>
    </action>
```

Hope this helped

And about the dateTextBox, I have the same problem as you have. I think it's because of the value returned. Ex : "**Wed Nov 16 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100**"